# Can I connect Data Visualization Tools to Salesforce Professional Edition?

Tags: professional-edition

Given that Salesforce Professional Edition restricts API access, can I connect BI tools with pre-built connectors to the Salesforce Pro Edition?  For example, Power BI has a Salesforce Content Pack that connects to Salesforce, will it work for Pro Edition?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on if the software was published by a certified ISV. ISV's are given a special "client ID" that allows them to bypass API restrictions on Professional Edition organizations. If you're not sure, check out their listing on the AppExchange or their documentation. If they are certified, it is likely that their software will run with your org. Contrariwise, if you're a developer yourself and you just write up some code in Java (or whatever language of choice), you'll find that it won't work on a Professional Edition org, because you don't have a Client ID.